# How can i use 2 components in react, one into other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I need to use two components, one of which will be underneath the other, and I need to interact with the two. To be more specific, I need to use the react-particles-js module, but I can not interact with it. I already tried to use the css z-index attribute, but it is not working.

```js
import Particles from 'react-particles-js'
import Screens from './screens'
...
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Screens /> //this component has all screens of my application, and i use zIndex:'1' into Inputs, TextFields, Buttons and others components of Semantic UI...
        <Particles
          params={params}
          style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '0', zIndex: '0' }}
        />
      </div>
    )


  }
}

class ScreensLogin extends Component {
  ...
  <Form.Group>
  <Form.Input
    style={{ marginBottom: '28px', zIndex: '1' }}
    onChange={this.handleChange("email")}
    autoComplete="on"
    type='text'
    name='email'
    placeholder='Email'
    icon='mail'
    iconPosition='left'
    width={16}
    id='fieldEmail'
  />
</Form.Group>
```

what i have to do to this code works correctly?

Comment: It's not working in what sense? Are you getting any errors or you simply doesnt see the particles appearing?

Comment: @Isaac, i can see it, but i can't interact with the mouse (repulse or grab)